# How to append data to the header in this case?

Tags: jquery

I wanted to produce HTML similar to shown in this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/pL7xugg1/16/

This is what i tried

https://jsfiddle.net/pL7xugg1/20/

But could you please why the header is missing ??

This is my code

```
var sampledata = 
[{
        "name": "John",
        "tip": "BUY 111",
        "time": "23-DEC"
    },

    {
        "name": "John",
        "tip": "BUY 232",
        "time": "23-DEC"
    }
]

for(var i=0;i<sampledata.length;i++)
{
var name = sampledata[i].name;
var tip = sampledata[i].tip;
var time = sampledata[i].time;

var html = '';

html+='<a href="#" class="c1">\
      <div class="stoc5 mt1">\
         <div class="c1 fl wi80">\
            <span class="fl c2 f14 ti-s mt">'+time+'</span>\
            '+tip+'\
         </div>\
         <div class="fr c2 f14 ti-s1 mt"></div>\
         <div class="cl"></div>\
      </div>\
   </a>';

   $(".hed1").html(html);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Include jQuery
2. Use DOM Ready before doing DOM Manipulation. `$(function(){ .... });`
3. Inside for loop dont set `.html()` instead append everytime using `.html()`
4. Dont append to `.hed` append to `.cl` that is the right div.

   ```
   $(function() {
       $(".cl").html(""); // Clearing the HTML
       for (var i = 0; i < sampledata.length; i++) {
           var name = sampledata[i].name;
           var tip = sampledata[i].tip;
           var time = sampledata[i].time;

           var html = '';

           html += '<a href="#" class="c1">\
     <div class="stoc5 mt1">\
        <div class="c1 fl wi80">\
           <span class="fl c2 f14 ti-s mt">' + time + '</span>\
           ' + tip + '\
        </div>\
        <div class="fr c2 f14 ti-s1 mt"></div>\
        <div class="cl"></div>\
     </div>\
      </a>';

       $(".cl").append(html);

   }
   });
   ```

## [***Live Fiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/pL7xugg1/21/)